# JQUERY + Browser Autocomplete

Tags: jquery

I have an input and autocomplete occurs on it - like all text inputs I assume.

I've been capturing keyup() events to check if the data is correct and let the user know with a tick.

The autocomplete however skips the keyup() event - how should I capture this event? I did see mention of capturing the  key. Is this correct?

Note: I have a few input type text on this page.

thx

Comment: show some code!! http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Comment: just remove autocomplete function by adding attribute autocomplete="off" to input

Answer (score 0):

Try binding to both **keyup** and **change** event, like:

```
$('yourInputTextEle').on('keyup change', function () {
    //your code here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend the creation of the autocomplete with a result. Something like this

```
$("#element").autocomplete("/url/")
    .result( 
        function (event, data, formatted) { 
            // Do something when selected
        }
    );
```